# How can I convert sql to linq in Sub Query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, subquery

```
select * 
from Vehicletab 
where LicencePlate not in (select LicencePlate 
                           from AssignVechiletab 
                           where IsAssign = 'true' 
                             and CreatedDate = '2018-10-29') 
  and VendorID = 1153
```

Comment: anyone please give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner select is independed from top one. So you can do this

```
var innerList = AssignVechiletab.Where(a => a.IsAssign && a.CreatedDate == "2018-10-29");
var mainList = Vehicletab.Where(v => !innerList.Contains(v.LicencePlate) && v.VendorID == 1153);
```

I don't know the type of the LicencePlate so I used Contains method. You can use relevent methods like IndexOf,...

Comment: LicencePlate  is string

Comment: i want to print list of items in vehicletable not Equal to assignVehicletable

Comment: Error 5 'System.Linq.IQueryable<RVAMS.DAL.MT_AssignDOVechile>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

What a pity you forgot to give us the requirements of your query! I'll have to guess from your SQL statement what you really want.

It seems to me, that you have a sequence of `AssignVehicleTabs`. Every `AssignVehicleTab` has at least properties `LicensePlate`, `IsAssign`, and `CreatedDate`.

Furthermore you have a sequence of `VehicleTabs`, where every `VehicleTab` has a `LicensePlate`.

You can make a query, that results in all `LicensePlates` of those `AssignVehicleTabs` that `IsAssign` and have a `CreatedDate` equal to 2018-10-29:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime (2018, 10, 29);
var assignedLicensePlatesOnMyDate = myDbContext.AssignVehicleTabs
    .Where(assignVehicleTabe => assignVehicleTab.IsAssign
                             && assignVehicleTabe.CreatedDate == myDate)
    .Select(assignVehicleTab => assignVehicleTab.LicensePlate);
```

In words: From the sequence of all `AssignVehicleTabs`, keep only those `AssignVehicleTabs` that are assigned and are created on `myDate`. From every remaining `AssignVehicleTab` get only the `LicensePlate`.

Note: the result is an `IQueryable<..>`: the query has been created, but not executed yet. No communication with the database was needed for this.

> The use of proper identifiers in your lambda expressions makes them
>   easier to read. Advice: use singular nouns for the objects that
>   represent one collection item, use plural nouns for object that
>   represent collections.

Now from the collection of `VehicleTabs` you want only the `VehicleTabs` that have a license plate in the sequence of `assignedLicensePlatesOnMyDate`.

For this you use [Queryable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_Contains__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0____0_):

```
var result = myDbContext.VehicleTabs
    .Where(vehicleTab => assignedLicensePlatesOnMyDate.Contains(vehicleTab.LicensePlate));
```

In words: from the collection of `VehicleTabs`, keep only those `VehicleTabs` that have a `LicensePlate` that is in `assignedLicensePlatesOnMyDate`.

Note that the query still hasn't been executed yet. Only LINQ function that don't return `IQueryable<...>` will execute the query. Think of `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Any()`, `Count()` etc. Internally they will call `foreach` and/or the lower level `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext`, which will execute the query.

It is up to you to decide whether you want to put this into one big LINQ query. This won't improve processing speed. It surely will deteriorate readability, and thus testability and maintainability.